# How to make components evenly share JPanel container vertical area with GridBagLayout layout on resizing?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

### The problem:

`JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` contains two `JScrollPane` components, the top one contains `JTextArea`, the bottom one contains `JTable`. I expect this set up to make the components ***fluidly fill*** the container `JPanel` and ***evenly share*** the vertical area of it on resizing. What actually happens is that the top `JScrollPane` component shrinks vertically on resizing giving more vertical area to the bottom `JScrollPane` component to invade; this happens at some sizes, I don not know if they are random.

### Important notes:

I already applied `GridBagConstraints#weighty = 0.5;` to both components, which is supposed to do the job.

I noticed that the problem is because of the presence of the `JTextArea`, in that if I **switch locations**; make the `JScrollPane/JTextArea` on the bottom side and `JScrollPane/JTable` on the top side; the bottom component `JScrollPane/JTextArea` shrinks vertically giving more vertical area to the top component `JScrollPane/JTable` to invade.

I know this exact case can be solved simply using `GridLayout(2,1)` instead of `GridBagLayout` (or may be other solutions), however I am fan of `GridBagLayout` and I want to use most of it. Also if I want to add three components instead of two and I want to make them share the vertical area by percentage for example (%25, %25, 50%) I can use `GridBagConstraints#weighty = (0.25, 0.25, 0.5)` which is easily applicable with `GridBagLayout`.

So, in this case how to make components ***evenly share*** the vertical area of `JPanel` container with `GridBagLayout` on resizing?. Or, in other words; how to enforce components to respect `GridBagConstraints#weighty = 0.5;` setting on resizing which is applied to both?

### Code in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) format:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GridBagFluidFill {

    private static JPanel createFormPanel() {

        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        containerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
        JScrollPane scrollableTextArea;
        JScrollPane scrollableTable;

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        scrollableTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}, 0);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        scrollableTable = new JScrollPane(table);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        // I expect this to reserve 50% of the height all time.
        c.weighty = 0.5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        containerPanel.add(scrollableTextArea, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        // I expect this to reserve 50% of the height all time.
        c.weighty = 0.5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        containerPanel.add(scrollableTable, c);

        return containerPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JPanel formPanel = createFormPanel();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagFluidFill");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(formPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the behaviour here, so it might be an artifact of the JRE being used. Having said that.. *"I am fan of `GridBagLayout`"* is a poor reason for not using a `GridLayout`, IMO.

Comment: Java Swing was not designed for proportional layouts as you described.  Give your JTable and your JTextArea the sizes they need and let the JFrame pack to whatever size needed.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc There are standard layouts which can do it.  It’s GridBagLayout which is not designed for proportional layouts.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for comment. No problem, I have to use `GridLayout`, I was wondering why `JTextArea` shrinks without a good reason, The SSCCE is just a minimal excerpt from a more complex GUI which I am working on, and I noticed this *shrink* behaviour to happen unreasonably to the `JScrollPane` which contains the `JTextArea`. Wherever I put it, it shrinks vertically on resize. I suppose the components to obey the setting `weighty`. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: *"The SSCCE is just a minimal excerpt from a more complex GUI"* BTW - yes it was a superb SSCCE. It was short, complete, straight to the point and allowed me to test the result with ease. It's handy to know even if the behaviour is different on different machines - at least then we can rule out the code as being the immediate problem. (Also, I wrote the SSCCE document, and love seeing it being of use to people!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already applied GridBagConstraints#weighty = 0.5; to both components, which is supposed to do the job.

The `weighty` constraint is used to tell the GridBagLayout how to allocate "extra" (and apparently less) space.

That is, each component is first allocated its preferred space. Then if there is extra (or apparently less) space available, that constraint is used.

If you add debug code to display the preferred sizes of each scroll pane you will get:

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=223,height=19] // text area
java.awt.Dimension[width=453,height=403] // table
```

So the issue is with this statement:

```
containerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
```

You are forcing the components to be smaller than their preferred size. So it appears the GridBagLayout is allocating 50% to each.

> I was wondering why JTextArea shrinks without a good reason

As the height of the frame grows each component is allocated 50% until the point at which the frame is large enough to display each component at its preferred size. This is why the text area shrinks and the table jumps.

As you increase the height from there extra space is allocated at 50/50 as expected.

If you uncomment the setPreferredSize() statement you will see the natural layout and the reason for the jumping becomes clear.

> I want to make them share the vertical area by percentage for example (%25, %25, 50%)

If you want allocations like that then check out [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which was designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

GridBagLayout is complex, and while its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) does describe all of its functionality, some of it is easy to misinterpret.

> I already applied `GridBagConstraints#weighty = 0.5;` to both components, which is supposed to do the job.

That is not what weightx and weighty do.

Equal weightx and weighty values do not coerce components into having the same width or height.  The weight values determine the distribution of *extra space* when a container is larger than the preferred sizes of each component.

Here is a program which demonstrates this:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GridBagEqualWeightsDemo {
    static void showWindow() {
        // Source: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/98/98-h/98-h.htm
        String text =
            "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was"
            + " the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the"
            + " epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the"
            + " season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the"
            + " spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything"
            + " before us, we had nothing before us, we were all going direct"
            + " to Heaven, we were all going direct the other way—in short,"
            + " the period was so far like the present period, that some of its"
            + " noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good"
            + " or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.";

        JTextArea topArea = new JTextArea(text, 4, 20);
        topArea.setLineWrap(true);
        topArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JTextArea bottomArea = new JTextArea(text, 8, 20);
        bottomArea.setLineWrap(true);
        bottomArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JScrollPane top = new JScrollPane(topArea);
        JScrollPane bottom = new JScrollPane(bottomArea);

        top.setMinimumSize(top.getPreferredSize());
        bottom.setMinimumSize(bottom.getPreferredSize());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1;

        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        panel.add(top, gbc);
        panel.add(bottom, gbc);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagConstraints Equal Weights");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> showWindow());
    }
}
```

As you can see, the two components start out with different preferred heights, so GridBagLayout will never give them the same height.  As you make the window taller, the components’ respective heights look more similar due to the smaller relative difference, but they are never the same.

GridBagLayout only uses the weighty to determine how to distribute the extra space—that is, the container height which exceeds each component’s (different) preferred height.  If the panel is 50 pixels higher than the preferred height, as computed based on each child component’s preferred size, then equal `weighty` values means each component will be laid out with 25 pixels added to its respective preferred height.

If you want to force two components which may have different preferred sizes to always have the same width and/or height, GridBagLayout is the wrong tool for the job.  As you have mentioned, GridLayout is well suited to this.  [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html) can also do this, though its usage is complex.

You are free (and encouraged!) to use multiple panels inside each other with different layouts.